# Xcode 6 Misplaced Views

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm creating layouts on storyboard and setting constraints. Let's say I have an UIImageView which fill screen width. Some time after i set it, it becomes smaller and gives misplaced view warning. I'm fixing the problem by updating frames, it fills screen width again but after some time, same problem occurs. And it's not just one view, it's same for half of my UIViewControllers /:

edit: maybe some screenshots help you to understand the situation;

I'm adding my components like below and setting constraints like 0 margin from left and right.
[image: this is what i want]

but after some time, it becomes like this by itself
[image: it becomes like this]

when i click update frames, it becomes what i want but for a short time..

Comment: A UIImageView gets its width from its image unless you give it an explicit width constraint (or constrain _both_ its sides).

Comment: By the way, this is not really a question. It's more of a moan...! To ask a question, show the specifics of what you're doing and ask about it. State what you're doing, what you expect, and what actually happens.

Comment: i edited my question, added some screenshots.

Comment: Aha, you see, you never said this had to do with prototype table view cells. That's important to know! - Okay, let me ask you this: does this make any difference when the app runs?

Comment: nope! app runs like how constraints are setted, just like how i want! it only affects how they look like on storyboard (and creates 30 annoying warnings)

Comment: Okay, I think you've found a bug. It's not a very important bug, really, because it doesn't affect anything about what happens at runtime; your constraints are obeyed. But I also think I can guess _why_ this bug is happening: it's because there is something odd about the _width_ of your view controllers. Notice the 80. Your view controller, I'm guessing, is 400 points wide - not the standard 320. You should be asking yourself how _that_ happened, I think.

Comment: It's probably about Xcode 6's new storyboard model, that squares. I selected **for all iPhones in portrait**. But your logic makes sense. I'll just report it and move on. Thanks for your help \o